# iOS - Parse Creating New Object - Object Not Found For Update

Tags: ios, parse-platform

So... this code was working a few days ago but I updated my Parse pod and now I'm having trouble saving newly created objects. The error tells me that the object was not found for update, but I'm not even trying to update an existing object - I'm making it new.

Here's my code:

```
PFUser *owner = [self.item objectForKey:@"user"];
PFUser *lendee = [PFUser currentUser];

PFObject *newRequest = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"ItemRequest"];
[newRequest setObject:owner forKey:@"owner"];
[newRequest setObject:lendee forKey:@"lendee"];
[newRequest setObject:self.item forKey:@"item"];

[newRequest saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error with saving: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has requested to borrow your %@", [lendee objectForKey:@"full_name"], [self.item objectForKey:@"title"]];
        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"sendEmailToUserWithId"
                           withParameters:@{@"userId" : owner.objectId,
                                            @"subject" : message,
                                            @"message" : message}
                                    block:^(id  _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                        if (error) {
                                            NSLog(@"Failed to send email with error: %@", error);
                                        }
                                    }];
    }
}];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly, either `owner` or `self.item` is a new, unsaved object.  Saving `newRequest` with pointers to those objects triggers an update to them.  One of those updates then fails with the message "object not found for update".

Log all three values being set on `newRequest`, looking for one or more that has no objectId (which is a good indicator that it is new).

Comment: Unfortunately all the items do have an objectId already. This issue started occurring after I updated Parse, my database has not changed nor is owner or self.item a new object.